# How to 'git cat-file' using exclusively Python?

Tags: python, git, zlib

I am trying to read out commit objects in git.

```
import zlib
import os

...

    for current, subs, files in os.walk('.'):
        for filename in files:
            
            path = os.path.join(current, filename)[2:]

            with open(path, 'rb') as file:
                
                # UTF-8
                # https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_discussion
                
                print(zlib.decompress(file.read()).decode())
```

The `zlib` decompression is not producing output the way I like. I have read the relevant sections in Pro Git, specifically: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects , which had instructions for Ruby. How can I accomplish this in Python?

Answer (score 2):

The linked documentation seems pretty clear.

> Git first constructs a header which starts by identifying the type of object — in this case, a blob. To that first part of the header, Git adds a space followed by the size in bytes of the content, and adding a final null byte:

Ruby is very similar to Python, so when the documentation shows:

```
>> content = "what is up, doc?"
=> "what is up, doc?"
>> header = "blob #{content.bytesize}\0"
=> "blob 16\u0000"
>> store = header + content
=> "blob 16\u0000what is up, doc?"
```

The Python code is almost identical:

```
>>> content = "what is up, doc?"
>>> header = f"blob {len(content)}\0"
>>> blob = header + content
>>> blob
'blob 16\x00what is up, doc?'
```

As both the prose and the code are showing us, when you read data from an object file you need to split it into a header and content. Something like:

```
with open(path, 'rb') as fd:
    data = zlib.decompress(fd.read())
    header, content = data.split(b'\0', 1)
    if header.startswith(b'commit'):
      print('found a commit in', path)
```

Comment: I see. Thanks. Just to be clear, I need to reference this always as a byte string? Coming from C/C++, this concept is more than a little confusing to me. That's why I had the additional `decode()` in my code, as I thought that it would be using `UTF-8`.

Comment: I didn't bother decoding anything here because it wasn't necessary. If you are reading UTF-8 encoded text, it makes sense to call `.decode()` *after* you split the header and content.

Comment: "as I thought that it would be using UTF-8." You thought wrong. Some objects may happen to be valid UTF-8, but many, e.g. tree objects, are not.

Comment: There is some interesting discussion on this topic [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree#_discussion).

Comment: read that @larsks . I'm assuming `UTF-8`. You can see I linked that in my post as well.

Comment: @MarkAdler i am only interested in commit objects.

Comment: So interestingly, what I've found is that commit contents are always UTF-8, but tree contents may not be.

Comment: Then only use commit objects. They start with "commit" after decompression. git objects always start with either "tree", "blob", "commit", or "tag".